# Data validation using VBA

Tags: excel, validation, vba

I am getting 'application defined or object defined object error' for the following code

```
10        Sheets("Main").Select
20        currYearDate = DateValue("April 1, " & Year(Now))
30        nextYearDate = DateValue("March 31, " & (Year(Now) + 1))
40        Range("H9").Activate
50        With ActiveCell.Validation
60            .Add Type:=xlValidateDate, AlertStyle:=2, Operator:=1, Formula1:=currYearDate, Formula2:=nextYearDate
70            .ErrorMessage = "You should enter date between " & Format(DateValue("April 1," & Year(Now)), "dd-mmm-yyyy") & " and " & Format(DateValue("March 31," & Year(Now) + 1), "dd-mmm-yyyy")
80            .ErrorTitle = "Warning Message"
90        End With
```

can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code :

```
 Sheets("Main").Select
    currYearDate = DateValue("April 1, " & Year(Now))
    nextYearDate = DateValue("March 31, " & (Year(Now) + 1))
    With Range("H9").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateDate, AlertStyle:=2, Operator:=1, Formula1:=currYearDate, Formula2:=nextYearDate
        .ErrorMessage = "You should enter date between " & Format(DateValue("April 1," & Year(Now)), "dd-mmm-yyyy") & " and " & Format(DateValue("March 31," & Year(Now) + 1), "dd-mmm-yyyy")
        .ErrorTitle = "Warning Message"
    End With
```